# How to set mount point for new esp partition?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 20.04, grub2, mount

I created a new empty `fat32` partition using GParted to install GRUB on because I want to separate GRUB from Windows Boot Manager

but `fstab` requires a mount point, this is the original line in fstab:

```
UUID=ABCD-1234 /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
```

The original mount point in `fstab` was `/boot/efi`.
What should the mount point be now?

When I use `lsblk` the mount point is empty.

And I can't use `mount -a` because it has no mount point

Comment: What's wrong with /boot/efi? You realize it's only mounted in case of a grub/shim update, nothing out there needs a mount for the running/booting of the system.

Comment: I'm total novice with this subject, so I'm probably completely misunderstanding this. I thought `/boot/efi` mount point means it's specific to the `sdb1` partition it's currently on and that I have to make a new mount point for `sdb5` (the new `fat32` partition), so that I can install grub there. you mean I can simply replace the UUID and leave the same `/boot/efi` and do `grub-install`? If I live the same mount point it won't install there? (The point is that I want to separate them). I'm completely confused

Comment: Thank you, my last confusion is regarding the mount point itself: For example `/boot/efi`, what is it? a directory? If it's a directory and I need to create a new one for the new mount point of `/boot/ubuntu`, how is it possible? Because `mkdir` would probably not make it in the new partition created. It will create it on the ext4 partition with the data, then it confuses me: Shouldn't the directory be inside the newly created partition? But how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

In your root filesystem, /boot/efi is an empty directory which is used as the mount point for the EFI partition.  The EFI partition has a FAT filesystem on it, with (typically) only one directory -- EFI.  Under EFI you may have other directories for different bootloaders -- Microsoft, ubuntu.   There is also a Boot directory which is the device default bootloader (no nvram entry needed, may be used as a fallback bootloader if your first choice fails, etc. but really only used if you have a removable disk and want to boot it).

See help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI Generally, you only have one EFI partition per bootable device, and the different operating systems' bootloaders are just put into different directories -- ...EFI/ubuntu, .../EFI/Microsoft, etc. The one place where grub does replace a Microsoft bootloader is the device default bootloader in .../EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi (but that one is typically not used on a one disk setup. That said, you may simple create another EFI, change the boot and ESP flags, and install grub there, but there's no need to bother doing that.

The grub installer knows about the directory structure on the EFI partition, and copies it's files (grubx64.efi and shimx64.efi) into the correct locations.  You really don't have to make anything yourself (even though the file setup is trivial copy two files to /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu and a three line grub.cfg stub file that imports the actual maintained grub.cfg file from /boot/grub/grub.cfg. Example of such a stub (change your UUID and disk/partition numbers) for your case:

```
$ sudo cat /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg
search.fs_uuid 0ac9e07b-c36d-473c-832c-030dab912345 root hd1,gpt2 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg
```

The other thing the grub installer does is to make the nvram entries to allow the ubuntu bootloaders to be selected from the EFI boot menu and be in the normal boot order.  You could do this manually too with efibootmgr, or set up the default bootloader (copy of grubx64.efi and shimx64.efi into .../EFI/Boot with shimx64.efi renamed to bootx64.efi.  Setting up the default bootloader lets you skip the nvram setup, since the device is always a boot choice.
It's not hard to do everything manually, but grub-installer really does it all  for you.

---

You can specify to grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/ubuntu if you really want to, and /boot/ubuntu is just a directory -- if you mount /dev/sda3 on /boot/ubuntu, then the files will go to sda3, not the mount point directory.  With the right flags, this may be used for booting, but don't expect any grub updates (the executables, not the grub.cfg file) to figure out your new EFI is not mounted at /boot/efi.  See the manual pages (man grub-install) for many more options. Are you trying to solve a problem, or is this just a learning experiment?

Comment: Thank you! My confusion is this: Let's say I have `sda2` as the large `ext4` partition and an empty 100MiB `sdb3` `fat32` partition for the new grub installation mount point. Now if `/boot/efi` is just an empty directory, and I want to install GRUB on my own custom directory, then I need to make an empty directory, say `/boot/ubuntu`. But I create the empty directory BEFORE mounting it, so it is now installed on `sda2` and not `sda3`, how does Ubuntu "know" to move this directory to `sda3` after I do `grub-install`?

Answer (score 0):

### Short Answer

Don't bother. There are few advantages to creating separate ESPs for Windows and Ubuntu, and doing so takes extra effort and makes it possible to create new problems.

### Long Answer

The answer by @ubfan1 is correct, AFAIK, but I'd like to emphasize and elaborate upon a few points....

First, there's really no need to create a separate ESP for Ubuntu. The ESP is *intended* to be shared across OSes. Creating more than one ESP, in fact, has the potential to cause problems -- some versions of Windows (or at least, the Windows installer) become confused by the presence of multiple ESPs, for instance. Thus, you may be creating problems down the road by creating a second ESP. That said, separating the Windows and Ubuntu boot loaders on different partitions *might* make the Ubuntu boot loader safer from meddling or mistakes by Windows, and vice-versa. If you're concerned about that, though, I'd suggest that creating a backup of the ESP on a USB flash drive, or even somewhere on the root (`/`) Linux filesystem and/or in Windows, would be good protection.

Second, Ubuntu expects the ESP to be mounted at `/boot/efi`. Although you can mount it elsewhere (or leave it unmounted until you need to modify it) and install GRUB 2 to that alternate mount point, this is a non-standard practice and might cause problems. Any script or tool that *assumes* the ESP will be mounted at `/boot/efi` is likely to misbehave if you mount the ESP elsewhere. Thus, you should mount the ESP at `/boot/efi`, period. If you have two ESPs, then "the" ESP means the ESP that holds the boot loader for the distribution installation in question. In your scenario of separate Windows and Ubuntu ESPs, there's no reason to mount the Windows ESP at all in Ubuntu. In fact, if the point of having two ESPs is to minimize the risk of one OS damaging the other's files, then you should definitely *not* mount the Windows ESP anywhere in Ubuntu. Instead, edit `/etc/fstab` so that you change the "UUID" (it's really a serial number, not a UUID, but that's another matter) that identifies the ESP so that it refers to your new Ubuntu-specific ESP, rather than the original ESP. (You can find the UUID/serial number of any partition with `blkid`, as in `sudo blkid /dev/sda1`.) You can then reboot or do a `sudo umount /boot/efi` followed by `sudo mount -a` to mount the Ubuntu-specific ESP at `/boot/efi`. Utilities and scripts should all work fine with that; you can do a `sudo grub-install` to install GRUB to the Ubuntu-specific ESP. (If GRUB has already been installed to the Windows ESP, you might want to temporarily mount it and remove those files.)

If you need to temporarily access the Windows ESP, then the mount point is unimportant. The `/mnt` directory is often used for this sort of thing; or various auto-mount tools will create subdirectories of `/media` for this purpose.

Third, 100 MiB is smaller than I recommend for an ESP. Although that provides enough space, it's got a couple of problems. First, `mkdosfs` will create a FAT16 filesystem on it, and some EFIs and OSes (including the installer for at least some versions of Windows) react badly to a FAT16 ESP. You can work around this by telling `mkdosfs` to create a FAT32 filesystem, but if you forget to do this, it'll create FAT16 by default. Second, some EFIs have bugs in their FAT drivers that cause them to misbehave with FAT32 filesystems smaller than 512 MiB. One common problem is that some files may seem to not be present to the EFI, even though Linux and Windows can both see all the files and filesystem check tools say that the filesystem is OK. If Shim, the main GRUB binary, or its configuration file on the ESP are affected, you won't be able to boot. For these reasons, and to compensate for the possibility of confusion between megabytes (MB; 1,000,000 bytes) and mebibytes (MiB; 1,048,576 bytes), I recommend creating an ESP that's at least 550 MiB in size. To be sure, you'll *probably* be OK with a 100 MiB ESP; but it *might* cause problems that will be difficult to diagnose. Note that if you've already got a sub-512MiB ESP and it's working OK, I don't recommend resizing or replacing it, since that operation is tedious and could cause bigger problems. The point of my advice to create a 550+ MiB ESP is to head off problems; if a smaller ESP is already working, then there are no problems.